# Trying to put data in mysql database using get results in strange errors

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

I'm trying to add data to my mysql database using a php GET method. 
Though when open the url for test purposes T get strange errors.

this is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "bernd-mysql.php-friends.de";
$username = "521_admin";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "521_rfid_test";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
echo "<br/>";

$var1=$_GET["value1"];
$var2=$_GET["value2"];

echo $var1;
echo "<br/>";
echo $var2;
echo "<br/>";

$query = "INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `firstName`)
VALUES ('".$var1."','".$var2."')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo "New record created successfully" . "<br />";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
#mysql_query($query,$conn);
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

When i open the url with *?value1=00001&value2=9999* attached i get the following output.

Connected successfully
00001
9999
Error: INSERT INTO accounts (id, firstName) VALUES ('00001','9999')
$query,$conn); mysql_close($conn); ?>

I'm pretty new to php and mysql so please bear with me :)

Comment: use **mysqli_close($conn);**  instead of **mysql_close($conn);**

Comment: What data type is `id` and `firstName`? And if you ever think of deploying your app, read about SQL Injection first.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: As you connect with `mysqli`, you must close the connection using `mysqli` and not `mysql`..

Comment: You should also not use the final closing php tag (`?>`). It is not required and _might_ cause lots of issues. Just remove it at the end of the file.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: If those fields are actually named `field1` and `field2` you're making life miserable for yourself. Name them with what they are.

Comment: A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so mistakes aren't easily ignored.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be due to your field "id" being an integer type in your database, if it's the case you shouldn't put coma in your VALUES for it, and always cast it to an integer, like this :

$query = "INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `firstName`)
VALUES (".(int)$var1.",'".$var2."')";

Comment: No! This even makes things worse, considering one should _never_ place client side provided data in a sql query using string concatenation. Please also read the comment @Quentin posted under the question.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's absolutly unsafe, I'm just answering about the sql error in this context.

Comment: The only situation where the detail you point out might lead to the described issue is _exactly_ a description of an sql injection. So what point is there in deliberately being silent in that point?

Comment: "I know this product I'm selling you will burn your house down, but it will also kill those pesky bedbugs."

Comment: He only asked about why he is getting an sql error, I told him what could be a cause. He also said that he was a beginner so I thought it would be a bit overkill to talk about security at this point when he just want to get his php working.